# How to make asynchronous alarm clock and webserver in micropython using uasyncio

Tags: python, asynchronous, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I have this code. It supports displaying alarm clock on the I2C display and should open webserver in the local WIFI that should not interrupt/stop the clock and work asynchronously. At this moment webserver is not even starting:

```
from machine import I2C, Pin, RTC
from pico_i2c_lcd import I2cLcd
import utime
from dht import DHT11
import uasyncio as asyncio
import network
import socket
import time
###################################################################
################Setup LCD I2C and initialize#######################
I2C_ADDR     = 0x27
I2C_NUM_ROWS = 2
I2C_NUM_COLS = 16

i2c = I2C(0, sda=machine.Pin(0), scl=machine.Pin(1), freq=400000)
lcd = I2cLcd(i2c, I2C_ADDR, I2C_NUM_ROWS, I2C_NUM_COLS)
lcd.backlight_on()
###################################################################

################Setup DS1302 and initialize###########################
rtc = RTC()
rtc.datetime() # returns the current datetime.
print(rtc.datetime())
######################################################################

#################initialize the Buzzer################################
buzzer = Pin(14, Pin.OUT)
buzzer.high()
######################################################################

#################Buttons#############################################
Button_pins = [6,7,8,9,10]
Button = []
# Loop to assign GPIO pins and setup input and outputs
for x in range(0,5):

    Button.append(Pin(Button_pins[x], Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP))
    Button[x].value(0)
######################################################################
    
    
#################Set initial values of alarm############################################# 
set_hour = 25
set_minute = 3
set_second = 00
hour = 0
minute = 0
#########################################################################################



DISPLAY_MODE_DATE_TIME = -1
DISPLAY_MODE_POGODA = 1
current_display_mode = DISPLAY_MODE_DATE_TIME

ssid = '2.4G-Vectra-WiFi-0CF5BA'
password = '5g01t2xz3wmfikmi'

html = """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> <title>Pico W</title> </head>
    <body> <h1>Pico W</h1>
        <p>%s</p>
    </body>
</html>
"""

wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)

utime.sleep(1)        

### Welcome Message ###           
lcd.move_to(0,0)
lcd.putstr("Projekt Systemy")
lcd.move_to(0,1)
lcd.putstr("Wbudowane")
utime.sleep(4)
lcd.clear()

def connect_to_network():
    wlan.active(True)
    wlan.config(pm = 0xa11140)  # Disable power-save mode
    wlan.connect(ssid, password)

    max_wait = 10
    while max_wait > 0:
        if wlan.status() < 0 or wlan.status() >= 3:
            break
        max_wait -= 1
        print('waiting for connection...')
        time.sleep(1)

    if wlan.status() != 3:
        raise RuntimeError('network connection failed')
    else:
        print('connected')
        status = wlan.ifconfig()
        print('ip = ' + status[0])

async def serve_client(reader, writer):
    print("Client connected")
    request_line = await reader.readline()
    print("Request:", request_line)
    # We are not interested in HTTP request headers, skip them
    while await reader.readline() != b"\r\n":
        pass

    request = str(request_line)
    led_on = request.find('/light/on')
    led_off = request.find('/light/off')
    print( 'led on = ' + str(led_on))
    print( 'led off = ' + str(led_off))

    stateis = ""
    if led_on == 6:
        print("led on")
        led.value(1)
        stateis = "LED is ON"

    if led_off == 6:
        print("led off")
        led.value(0)
        stateis = "LED is OFF"

    response = html % stateis
    writer.write('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-type: text/html\r\n\r\n')
    writer.write(response)

    await writer.drain()
    await writer.wait_closed()
    print("Client disconnected")


def show_on_display(lcd, line1, line2):
    lcd.clear()
    lcd.putstr(line1)
    lcd.move_to(0, 1)
    lcd.putstr(line2)

    
def read_temperature_and_humidity():
    dht_pin = 15  # GP14 pin
    dht_sensor = DHT11(Pin(dht_pin))
    dht_sensor.measure()
    temperature = dht_sensor.temperature()
    humidity = dht_sensor.humidity()
    return temperature, humidity
    

def set_alarm():
    
    global set_hour
    global set_minute
    global set_second
    global hour
    global minute
    
    lcd.clear()
    lcd.move_to(0,0)
    lcd.putstr("Set hour:")
    
    while Button[3].value() != 0:    
        if Button[1].value() == 0:
            set_hour += 1
            utime.sleep(0.1)
            set_hour = set_hour%24
            
        elif Button[2].value() == 0:
            set_hour -= 1
            utime.sleep(0.1)
            set_hour = set_hour%24
            
        hour = str(set_hour)
        
        while len(hour) < 2:
            hour = '0' + hour
        
        lcd.move_to(10,0)
        lcd.putstr(str(hour))
        
    lcd.clear()
    utime.sleep(0.3)
    lcd.move_to(0,0)
    lcd.putstr("Set minute:")
    
    while Button[3].value() != 0:
        if Button[1].value() == 0:
            set_minute += 1
            utime.sleep(0.1)
            set_minute = set_minute%60
        
        elif Button[2].value() == 0:
            set_minute -= 1
            utime.sleep(0.1)
            set_minute = set_minute%60
        
        minute = str(set_minute)
        while len(minute) < 2:
            minute = '0' + minute
            
        lcd.move_to(12,0)
        lcd.putstr(str(minute))
    
    lcd.clear()
    
    return(set_hour,set_minute)

def play_sound():
    global alarm_playing
    if alarm_playing:
        # Trigger the ISD1820 to play sound (assuming connected to pin 26, change as needed)
        isd1820_pin = Pin(26, Pin.OUT)
        isd1820_pin.value(1)
        time.sleep_ms(100)  # Adjust the delay based on your module's specifications

        # Read potentiometer value to control pitch
        pot_value = potentiometer_adc.read_u16()

        # Map the analog value to a frequency range (adjust as needed)
        mapped_frequency = int((pot_value / 65535.0) * 1000) + 100

        # Play sound with the adjusted frequency
        play_note(mapped_frequency, alarm_duration_ms)

        isd1820_pin.value(0)
        time.sleep_ms(50)  
        
    
def check_alarm(set_hour,set_minute,set_second):
     
    if set_hour == int(weekday) and set_minute == int(hr) and set_second == int(m) :

        while Button[3].value() != 0:
            lcd.clear()
            lcd.move_to(4,0)
            lcd.putstr("Wake Up!")
            
            utime.sleep(1)
            buzzer.low()
            utime.sleep(1)
            buzzer.high()
            lcd.clear()
    buzzer.high()



def clock():
    global current_display_mode, weekday, hr, m, s
    while True:
        (Y,M,D,day,weekday,hr,m,s)=rtc.datetime()
        if s < 10:
            s = "0" + str(s)
        if m < 10:
            m = "0" + str(m)
        if hr < 10:
            hr = "0" + str(hr)
        if D < 10:
            D = "0" + str(D)
        if M < 10:
            M = "0" + str(M)
            
        if Button[4].value() == 0:
            utime.sleep(0.1)
            current_display_mode *= -1
                      
        if current_display_mode == -1:

            lcd.move_to(0,0)
            lcd.putstr("Time:")
            lcd.move_to(6,0)
            lcd.putstr(str(weekday) + ":" + str(hr) + ":" + str(m))
            lcd.move_to(0,1)
            lcd.putstr("Date: ")
            lcd.move_to(6,1)
            lcd.putstr(str(D) + "/" + str(M) + "/" + str(Y))
            
            if Button[0].value() == 0:
                utime.sleep(0.1)
                print("Set Alarm")
                set_alarm()
        else:
            print("Showing temperature and humidty")
            temperature, humidity = read_temperature_and_humidity()
            show_on_display(lcd, f"Temp: {temperature} C", f"Humidity: {humidity}%")
            utime.sleep(1)
     
        check_alarm(set_hour,set_minute,set_second)
        
async def main():
    print('Connecting to Network...')
    connect_to_network()

    print('Setting up webserver...')
    asyncio.create_task(asyncio.start_server(serve_client, "0.0.0.0", 80))

    print('Starting clock...')
    asyncio.create_task(clock())

try:
    asyncio.run(main())
finally:
    asyncio.new_event_loop()
```

I tried to put `async def` before `clock()` function, but it doesn't help. I am clueless at this moment.